# Text element in a unknown height container

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

It is a little hard for me to describe what I want to do without an image:

[image]

**Some Background -** These are things I can't change or don't want to change:

I use this card layout for my blog front page. The card's width is calculated by javascript(according to different screen width) so it is unknown to CSS, the height is equal to width(I want the card to be a Square), the image's ratio is always 16:9. In the content area, The title doesn't wrap, the footer is just a date, but the texts' length is unknown(It is unknown because every blog post could have different intro text length. Besides, when in wider screen and the card's width is larger, I want the more intro text to be displayed so the space is filled up)

**Problem**

If the text is too long or the card's width is too small(on smaller screen), the text will stick out of the container and the footer will be pushed down, even though I set "overflow:hidden" for it.

[image]

So how do I make sure the text div doesn't push down the footer if the text is too  long for the card's width? (a.k.a, how do I make sure its height equal to the card's height minus image's height minus title div's height and  minus footer div's height). This shouldn't be hard using javascript, but can it be done with pure CSS? Flexbox seems handy for this by making the text div to grow, but it didn't work as I thought it would, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hnvm20b/) - It doesn't work without setting a fixed height for the flex container, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hnvm20b/1/) where a certain height is set for the flex container. Codes are here:

```
<style>
.card{
  border:1px solid #000
}
.container{
  padding-top:100%;
  position:relative;

}
.item{
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;position:absolute
}
.teaser{
  padding-top:56.25%;
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/320x180?text=%20');
}
.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:150px;   /* fixed height makes it work */
}
.title{overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis}
.title, .intro, .info{padding:10px}
.intro{overflow:hidden}
</style>
<div class="card" style="width:360.25px">  <!-- width calculated by javascript -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="teaser">

     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <div class="title">
          A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title A Blog Title 
        </div>
        <div class="intro">
          Some Intro text Some Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro textSome Intro text
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <time>2019-10-23</time>
        </div>   
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can this problem be solved by pure CSS?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What do you want to have happen if the text is too long?  Does it resize the container or does it wrap into hidden space?

Comment: I updated the question, I want the card to be a square, so if text is too long, it should not resize the container, but wrap into hidden space.

Comment: I don't get it. Any style, applied by js or css, would have same effect.

Comment: I reword the question hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

```
// you have not set min and max height of that container please add max and min height of intro.div it will work.

.intro {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 65px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: How do I know what value to set for min/max height if the container's height is unknown? See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2860q1e/1/

Comment: Sir if you running a blog you have to set the outer container max and min height otherwise its will collapse your whole page layout .If you want to solve this issue then you can use flex  see attached link https://codeburst.io/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly , but if you will add 
`flex-wrap:wrap;` to your `.title, .intro`

```
.title{flex-wrap:wrap;}
.intro{flex-wrap:wrap;}
```

and remove the container padding , it should work...

```
.card{
  border:1px solid #000
}
.container{
 /* padding-top:100vh;*/
  position:relative;

}
.item{
 /*  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;position:absolute */
}
.teaser{
  padding-top:56.25%;
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/320x180?text=%20');
}
.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;

}
.title{flex-wrap:wrap;}
.title, .intro, .info{padding:10px}
.intro{flex-wrap:wrap;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6q0tLobr/

Comment: I want to make sure the container is a square.

Comment: ok, so I did not get what you want exactly, so if you have a big title / text you want to crop it  like https://jsfiddle.net/cf19ebLn/ ?

Comment: Yes. The bottom line is the cards maintain a fixed dimension. There are lots of these cards in my page, I want them to be aligned